# *ngFor is not working angular for calling data from api

Tags: node.js, angular, multidimensional-array, angular-directive

I am trying to get data from api and show it on frontend but *ngFor is not working I checked all variables are working correctly and the data is showing in console.log but not showing on frontend, below I have shared you screenshot for the same

Thank you in advance,

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you sure your data has "desc" property?

Comment: I recommend placing some static text along with the {{data.desc}} so you can see if the ngFor is iterating or not, then looking at the 'desc' property and casing as suggested above.

Comment: I tried implementing some static text but *ngFor is not working

Comment: Please share the responses as a JSON, not as an image

Answer (score 0):

you declear the projects property in any but this is array.so  projects property declear projects:any=[]; like this

Comment: still not working